# Laravel - Working with multiple records, how do I pull the data I need?

Tags: laravel, records, laravel-3

WARNING:: LARAVEL SUPER-BEGINNER, BE GENTLE::

In my controller:

```
public function get_index(){
$lease_rates = DB::table('lease_rates');
$this->layout->nest('content','admin.lease_rates', array('lease_rates' => $lease_rates, ));
```

In my lease_rates table:

```
   id   lease_year   class_letter   rate
    1      2012           A          635
    2      2012           B          648
   ...     ....          ...         ...
    5      2012           E          789
    6      2011           A          629
```

In my lease_rates.blade.php:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="{{ $lease_rates->rate->find(1) }}" 
       value="{{ $lease_rates->rate->find(1) }}">

<input type="text" 
       name="{{ $lease_rates->rate->find(2) }}" 
       value="{{ $lease_rates->rate->find(2) }}">
```

Obviously the above doesn't work.  The end result that I want:

- Sort the array sent to the page by lease_year, descending then by class_letter ascending.
- Put the values of the rate for each id into text boxes where the textbox name is the id and the text displayed is the rate for said id.
- After that works, I'll need to submit any changes made to the table
- After that, I'll work on adding records

Thanks so much!  Like I said, I'm new, but eager to learn (and even more eager to get this thing done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the docs for the Fluent Query Builder (or Eloquent ORM)? http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent

You could do something like this (not checked, but you should get the idea):

```
//In your controller
$lease_rates = DB::table('lease_rates')->order_by('lease_year', 'desc')->order_by('class_letter', 'desc')->get();

//In your view
@foreach($lease_rates as $lease_rate)
    <input type="text" name="{{ $lease_rate->id) }}" value="{{ $lease_rate->rate }}">
@endforeach


//Save controller
foreach(Input::all() as $id => $rate){
    DB::table('lease_rates')->where('id', '=', $id)
    ->update(array('rate' => rate));
}
```

You could also use the Eloquent ORM, to make it even easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It /almost/ works perfectly.  For some reason, it is shifting the save values to different ids... weird...

Comment: I figurted out a solution:  I had to add a hidden field with name "0" value=0 so that it would fill the //apparently// invisible id=0 with something other than id=1's data.